# @auth.requires_permission not working

Tags: python, web2py

I have an application where I am using web2py's access control system. I have various users in **auth_user** table. To be more specific I have **admin1@mysite.com** user whose id is 4. There is a group **admin** with group id 1 in **auth_group** table. In **auth_membership** table I have **user_id** 4 related to **group_id** 1. It means that **admin1@mysite.com** is a member of **admin** group. Finally in **auth_permission** table I have a record which relates **group_id** 1 with permission named **search**. It means that **admin** group has **search** permission. I have a controller in which I have index method with decorator as **@auth.requires_permission('search')**. I am logging in with **admin1@mysite.com** and getting to this controller method. But this condition evaluates to false and control doesn't go inside method. However if I replace this decorator with one **@auth.requires_login()** it works. But I want only users with search permission to get access to this method. Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Did you create the permission by doing `auth.add_permission(1, 'search')`, or `db.auth_permission.insert(group_id=1, name='search')`, or by entering a record in db.auth_permission via the appadmin interface?

Comment: I directly inserted it in database table. group_id=1, name=search.

Comment: It has been fixed. I inserted this record by doing **auth.add_permission(1, 'search')**. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When entering a record in the `db.auth_permission` table, there is a `table` field in addition to the `name` field (note, `table` doesn't have to refer to a database table -- it can be any name representing any type of object). When a permission is checked, both the `name` and the `table` must match.

If you insert a permission record via the appadmin interface or using `auth.add_permission(1, 'search')`, then the `table` field will be set to an empty string (i.e., ''). This will work, because when you do `@auth.requires_permission('search')`, that is equivalent to `@auth.requires_permission('search', '')`, which matches the empty string in the permission record.

However, if you insert via `db.auth_permission.insert(group_id=1, name='search')`, then the `table` field will be set to `None`, which will not match the empty string when you check the permission.